# What is this Git in Xcode4.?

Tags: xcode, git, svn, version-control

I Just Installed XCode 4.
I came across some new words while reading the transition guide

What is this git and SCM in Xcode4 mean?
What purpose does these serve?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCM stands for `software control management`, and git is a example of such software.

Another example is Subversion (SVN), which is perhaps (for the moment) more known, and is also available in Xcode.

Git has the advantage to be distributed, which means you don't need to have another server or anything to start your versioning control.

A small quote from [git](http://git-scm.com/):

> Git is a free & open source, distributed version control system
>   designed to handle everything from small to very large projects with
>   speed and efficiency.
>
> Every Git clone is a full-fledged repository with complete history and
>   full revision tracking capabilities, not dependent on network access
>   or a central server. Branching and merging are fast and easy to do.
>
> Git is used for version control of files, much like tools such as
>   Mercurial, Bazaar, Subversion, CVS, Perforce, and Team Foundation
>   Server.

You can see the Apple [words on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well git and scm are two popular options for Managing Versions of Your Project. [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html) apple document helps you understand them..